# Parse a text file, get values of every 15th and 16th line

Tags: tcl

So basically the text file has values that I want to obtain that occur every 15 and 16th line repeatedly for the entire file. So lines 1-14 are irrevelent, then I want to obtain the values of lines 15 and 16, then lines 17-30 are irrelevent, and then I want the values of line 31 and 32, etc etc until the end of file

Answer (score 2):

If your use case allows use of the command line, this can be easily done with `awk`:

```
[samiller@local ~/tmp/h] sed -n '15~16{N;p}' 1.txt
15
16
31
32
```

Comment: I think you want `15~16` here to match lines 31 and 32.

Comment: Indeed.  Corrected.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This regex works `(?:(.*\r?\n)(.*\r?\n)){8}\K`. Every match will be 2 lines and the first capt. group will be the first line and the second one the second line. Demo here: https://regex101.com/r/NJlcrN/1

Answer (score 0):

You just need to keep count of lines while you're processing the file

```
exec seq 50 > nums.txt
set fh [open nums.txt r]
set nr 0
while {[gets $fh line] != -1} {
    set nr [expr {($nr + 1) % 16}]
    if {1 <= $nr && $nr <= 14} then continue
    # do something with lines 15 & 16
    puts $line
}
close $fh
```

```
15
16
31
32
47
48
```